# Importing all tables into HBase via Sqoop

Tags: mysql, hbase, sqoop

Operating System: Windows

With this [reference](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_importing_data_into_hbase) I can import specific table into HBase; But how can I import all tables of a database into HBase as separate tables?

**Sqoop command to import all tables from database into a single HBase table**

```
sqoop import-all-tables --hbase-table testhbaseall --hbase-create-table  --column-family hr  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/madha --username root --password sa  --warehouse-dir /user/h40/hr -m 1 --hbase-row-key Id
```

Executing this command results in data loss (Overwrite existing data in HBase table)

I just need to know whether this is correct behavior or not

Comment: It looks difficult as different table will have different row-keys .., so i guess it is not possible. In the future if this feautre comes it will be helpfiul

Answer (score 1):

When we use import-all-tables, the source (DB) and destination (HDFS or Hive), can maintain similar format. However, when you want all tables in DB to be in Hbase, the structure in which they are stored is different, as we need column families in Hbase. How are we going to manage that for entire DB. There is no documentation given there to import all tables into Hbase. So, you might have to try other ways of loading data into HBase. Even I am looking for any answer on this aspect.